# Download file once a visitor has entered their email address into a form

Tags: php, jquery

Is there a way that I can have a "download file" link on a website but one that only downloads the file once a visitor has entered their email address into a form first?

Kind of like this system that Premium Pixels has, where you have to be a member to download things - http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/social-media-sharing-buttons-psd/

Comment: Use AJAX to submit the email address, verify that it's valid, then return the URL of the link to the browser. Of course, this doesn't verify that the user has submitted their own email address, just SOMEBODY'S email address. The best way to do *that* is to send the URL to whatever email address they provide.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a session if you want the user to be able to download multiple files but only enter their email address once.

On the link send them to a form which posts to a PHP page, then it processes that form and if the user did enter an e-mail then set the session to true e.g.

User clicks download
Check if session for download is yes/valid/true
if session isn't valid
  Show basic HTML form asking for e-mail
Process HTML form and set the session for download yes/valid/true
Show "real" download link

EDIT:
As Blaze mentioned the best bet is to send the link to the e-mail to ensure that they provide THEIR e-mail and not someone elses

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sending a direct link to the file once you have verified the user, it would be better to keep the file in a protected directory on your web server and send it to the users browser using [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). So take the form page, process the input and validate it, if your validator is happy and the form is submitted have it provide the download. The file should pop up as a download in the users browser without sending a direct link. You should be able to get it working using the example in the PHP docs as your guide.